# Showing image inside JLabel which is stored in database by clicking Button

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans-8

In Netbeans I took a Desktop Pane and inside that pane I took Label.Inside the Label I want to show image which is already stored in Database(sqlite manager) by clicking a button.This is the code I've tried,

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try
    {
        String sql = "Select Image from EmployeeInfo where EmployeeId=1";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("Image");
            format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
            lbl_image.setIcon(format);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I also declared a global variable in my code,

```
private ImageIcon format = null;
```

But it is not showing the picture when I click the button.It is not giving any error or exception.Program run successfully but not showing image inside the Label.I can't figure out what I did wrong and what to do to solve it.I am a beginner in java.Anyone help me please.

Comment: First off, you haven't assigned `rs`. Secondly, if `rs.next()` returns false (ie. the query returned no rows) then it will just exit nicely without doing anything. Either debug it or add some logging -> try log4j or slf4j or even System.out.

Comment: @TedTrippin Sorry I don't get it.Could you please explain exactly what I need to do. :(
And I think I assigned rs,
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;

public EmployeeInfo() {

    initComponents();
    conn=JavaConnect.ConnectDb();
}

Comment: It looks like you should have `rs = pst.executeQuery();` but hard to say since you've only provided parts of your code.

Comment: OMG!!! It works!!! I've tried lots of things but may be except this one which is needed -_-
Thank you so much. :) @TedTrippin

Comment: I've posted an answer so you can accept it

Comment: You clearly need to learn the basics before moving on. Take the time to learn and you will have a less frustrating time asking a question every 5 minutes and a more enjoyable programming experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot...

```
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```